# Json file is not working/not reading jsonarray cannot be converted to jsonobject

Tags: java, php, android, json

Hello I want to access my web records in my android app. By doing so, I use JSON to do that and PHP. This is the url of my json file: [here](http://www.shoppersgroup.net/vanmanagement/results.php)

But the problem is it's just displaying the php code. I need to be able to access/read that file. :( Any ideas what I am doing in here? Help is much appreciated by me. thanks.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
    <?php 

    include('connectdb.php');
    $sql = "SELECT salesordercard_code, location_from, location_to, salesmancode FROM salesorderingcard";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);    
    if($result === FALSE) {
     die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
    }
    $set = array();
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $set[] = $row1;
    }

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($set);


    ?>
```

MainActivity.class

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array 
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Retrive JSON Objects from the given website URL in JSONfunctions.class
        jsonobject = JSONFunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://www.shoppersgroup.net/vanmanagement/results.php");

        try {
            // Locate the array name
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("posts");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                //Log.i(MainActivity.class.getName(), jsonobject.getString("movie_name"));
                // Retrive JSON Objects
                map.put(TAG_CODE, jsonobject.getString("salesordercard_code"));
                map.put(TAG_LOCATION_FROM, jsonobject.getString("location_from"));
                map.put(TAG_LOCATION_TO, jsonobject.getString("location_to"));
                // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                arraylist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
}
```

**Logcat:**

```
            11-18 02:35:08.521: E/log_tag(1047): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [{"salesmancode":"SLMAN001","location_to":"MAIN","location_from":"IN-TRANSIT","salesordercard_code":"SLESO0001"},{"salesmancode":"SLMAN001","location_to":"MAIN","location_from":"IN-TRANSIT","salesordercard_code":"SLESO0002"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jsonarray cannot be converted to jsonobject/json not working Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039334/jsonarray-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject-json-not-working-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First as Json String

```
[ // Its an Array
    "posts",// Its not an Array and its index is 0 so we will not use index 0
    {//Index1
        "salesordercard_code": "SLESO0001",
        "location_from": "IN-TRANSIT",
        "location_to": "MAIN",
        "salesmancode": "SLMAN001"
    },
    {//index2
        "salesordercard_code": "SLESO0002",
        "location_from": "IN-TRANSIT",
        "location_to": "MAIN",
        "salesmancode": "SLMAN001"
    }
]
```

Change your doInBackground() method like below,

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array 
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Retrive JSON Objects from the given website URL in JSONfunctions.class
        jsonobject = JSONFunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://www.shoppersgroup.net/vanmanagement/results.php");

        try {
            // Locate the array name
            jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonobject.toString());

            for (int i = 1; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {// strat from index1 
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONObject jsonobj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                //Log.i(MainActivity.class.getName(), jsonobj.getString("movie_name"));
                // Retrive JSON Objects
                map.put(TAG_CODE, jsonobj.getString("salesordercard_code"));
                map.put(TAG_LOCATION_FROM, jsonobj.getString("location_from"));
                map.put(TAG_LOCATION_TO, jsonobj.getString("location_to"));
                // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                arraylist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, but I got this logcat errors:         11-18 03:14:32.080: E/WindowManager(1621): Activity com.innovalynx.vanmanagementsystem.SalesOrder has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d13098 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-480,243} that was originally added here
  11-18 03:14:32.080: E/WindowManager(1621): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.innovalynx.vanmanagementsystem.SalesOrder has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d13098 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-480,243} that was originally added here

Comment: @Dunkey did you get any json Exception. Have you check the log wether parsing is working well. As WindowleakExcepion occur when you are trying to show Dialog when there is no window.

Comment: I didn't get json exception but what I typed above those only are the errors

Answer (score 0):

Your `results.json` file can't run php because it isn't being processed as PHP, its being processed as a json file, and as such it is displaying the text within it as text.

Rename it to `results.php` and attempt it then, it should print out the json encoded data with the results you need.

Comment: It is being printed like this: [{"salesordercard_code":"SLESO0001","location_from":"IN-TRANSIT","location_to":"MAIN","salesmancode":"SLMAN001"},{"salesordercard_code":"SLESO0002","location_from":"IN-TRANSIT","location_to":"MAIN","salesmancode":"SLMAN001"}]

Comment: But I can't access it in my android app.

Comment: I've added my logcat. Error parsing JSON

Comment: I don't know much about the android app side of things but it sounds like you're trying to reference an array as an object?