# jsonarray cannot be converted to jsonobject/json not working Android

Tags: php, android, json

This is what I've tried so far:

```
    <?php 

    include('connectdb.php');
    $sql = "SELECT salesordercard_code, location_from, location_to, salesmancode FROM salesorderingcard";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);    
    if($result === FALSE) {
     die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
    }
    $set = array();
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $set[] = $row1;
    }

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($set);


    ?>
```

MainActivity.class

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array 
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Retrive JSON Objects from the given website URL in JSONfunctions.class
        jsonobject = JSONFunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://www.shoppersgroup.net/vanmanagement/results.php");

        try {
            // Locate the array name
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("posts");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Retrive JSON Objects
                map.put(TAG_CODE, jsonobject.getString("salesordercard_code"));
                map.put(TAG_LOCATION_FROM, jsonobject.getString("location_from"));
                map.put(TAG_LOCATION_TO, jsonobject.getString("location_to"));
                // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                arraylist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
}
```

**Logcat:**

```
            11-18 02:35:08.521: E/log_tag(1047): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [{"salesmancode":"SLMAN001","location_to":"MAIN","location_from":"IN-TRANSIT","salesordercard_code":"SLESO0001"},{"salesmancode":"SLMAN001","location_to":"MAIN","location_from":"IN-TRANSIT","salesordercard_code":"SLESO0002"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

But still I there is someting wrong with my jsonArray. What am I missing here? I really your help guys. Thanks.

Comment: i see no jsonarray by name posts

Comment: @Raghunandan please do check my string url. I have posts there

Comment: possible duplicate of [Json file is not working/not reading jsonarray cannot be converted to jsonobject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039013/json-file-is-not-working-not-reading-jsonarray-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you get is a `JSONArray` not a `JSONObject`.

```
JSONArray jr= new JSONArray("jsonstring");
```

Your JSON looks like below

```
[          // json array node
    {      // json object
        "salesordercard_code": "SLESO0001",  // string
        "location_from": "IN-TRANSIT",
        "location_to": "MAIN",
        "salesmancode": "SLMAN001"
    },
    {
        "salesordercard_code": "SLESO0002",
        "location_from": "IN-TRANSIT",
        "location_to": "MAIN",
        "salesmancode": "SLMAN001"
    }
]
```

Change `getJSONfromURL`

```
public static String getJSONfromURL(String url){ 

String _respone=null;

// Download JSON data from URL 
try{ 
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url); 
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
_response=EntityUtils.toString(entity); 
 Log.i(".......",_response); 
}
catch(Exception e)
{
     e.printStacktrace();
}
return _response; 

}
```

Then

```
String result = JSONFunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://www.shoppersgroup.net/vanmanagement/results.php");
JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(result);
 for(int i=0;i<jr.length();i++)
 {
          JSONObject jb = (JSONObject)jr.get(i);
          String salesorder= jb.getString("salesordercard_code");
          //similarly for location_from...
 }
```

Comment: Basically, I'm getting the records from the web, but I don't want to programmatically declare them in my java code.

Comment: @Dunkey i din't understand what you meant by programmatically declare them in java

Comment: I meant this one: JSONArray jr= new JSONArray("jsonstring");

[
    {
        "salesordercard_code": "SLESO0001",
        "location_from": "IN-TRANSIT",
        "location_to": "MAIN",
        "salesmancode": "SLMAN001"
    },
    {
        "salesordercard_code": "SLESO0002",
        "location_from": "IN-TRANSIT",
        "location_to": "MAIN",
        "salesmancode": "SLMAN001"
    }
]

Comment: @Dunkey that is not in java. i posted that so that you can look at the json. Use the code below To parse.

Comment: @Dunkey i posted it to make you understand what is a json array and a json object. all you need to add is the code to parse the json. and add to map add the map to arraylist

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41376/discussion-between-dunkey-and-raghunandan)

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is an array because there is no object in it so how can you get a JSONObject from it.

```
[
{
    "salesmancode": "SLMAN001",
    "location_to": "MAIN",
    "location_from": "IN-TRANSIT",
    "salesordercard_code": "SLESO0001"
},
{
    "salesmancode": "SLMAN001",
    "location_to": "MAIN",
    "location_from": "IN-TRANSIT",
    "salesordercard_code": "SLESO0002"
}
```

]

You need to convert your json in a String ,then pass it like this

```
    String json = byteArrayOutputStream.toString(); // YOur json here. I am getting it via a local file
    System.out.println(json);
    JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(json);      
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++) {
        JSONArray innerJsonArray = obj.getJSONArray(i);
        JSONObject jsonObject = innerJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
        String areaID = jsonObject.getString("Key"); // Your json key goes here
        String Icon = jsonObject.getString("Value"); // Your json key goes here
    }
```